# How to create a dependency between observables?

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I want a tool for testing Rx components that would work like this:
Given an order of the events specified as a `'v seq` and a key selector function (`keySelector :: 'v ->  'k`) I want to create a `Map<'k, IObservable<'k>>` where the guarantee is that the groupped observables yield the values in the global order defined by the above enumerable.

For example:
`makeObservables isEven [1;2;3;4;5;6]`
...should produce

```
{ true : -2-4-6|,
  false: 1-3-5| }
```

This is my attempt looks like this:

```
open System
open System.Reactive.Linq
open FSharp.Control.Reactive

let subscribeAfter (o1: IObservable<'a>) (o2 : IObservable<'b>) : IObservable<'b> =
    fun (observer : IObserver<'b>) ->
        let tempObserver = { new IObserver<'a> with
                                member this.OnNext x = ()
                                member this.OnError e = observer.OnError e
                                member this.OnCompleted () = o2 |> Observable.subscribeObserver observer |> ignore
                            }
        o1.Subscribe tempObserver
    |> Observable.Create

let makeObservables (keySelector : 'a -> 'k) (xs : 'a seq) : Map<'k, IObservable<'a>> =
    let makeDependencies : ('k * IObservable<'a>) seq -> ('k * IObservable<'a>) seq = 
        let makeDep ((_, o1), (k2, o2)) = (k2, subscribeAfter o1 o2)

        Seq.pairwise
        >> Seq.map makeDep

    let makeObservable x = (keySelector x, Observable.single x)

    let firstItem = 
        Seq.head xs 
        |> makeObservable 
        |> Seq.singleton

    let dependentObservables =
        xs
        |> Seq.map makeObservable
        |> makeDependencies

    dependentObservables
    |> Seq.append firstItem
    |> Seq.groupBy fst
    |> Seq.map (fun (k, obs) -> (k, obs |> Seq.map snd |> Observable.concatSeq))
    |> Map.ofSeq

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let isEven x = (x % 2 = 0)

    let splits : Map<bool, IObservable<int>> =
        [1;2;3;4;5]
        |> makeObservables isEven

    use subscription =
        splits
        |> Map.toSeq
        |> Seq.map snd
        |> Observable.mergeSeq
        |> Observable.subscribe (printfn "%A")


    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

...but the results are not as expected and the observed values are not in the global order.

Apparently the items in each group are yield correctly but when the groups are merged its more like a concat then a merge

The expected output is: `1 2 3 4 5`
...but the actual output is `1 3 5 2 4`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe wanting this:

```
{ true : -2-4-6|,
  false: 1-3-5| }
```

But you're really creating this:

```
{ true : 246|,
  false: 135| }
```

Since there's no time gaps between the items in the observables, the `merge` basically has a constant race condition. Rx guarantees that element 1 of a given sequence will fire before element 2, but `Merge` offers no guarantees around cases like this.

You need to introduce time gaps into your observables if you want `Merge` to be able to re-sequence in the original order.

Comment: There are no timegaps but the subscribeAfter should produce an observable that only yields after the first parameter completes. Shouldn't that guarantee the ordering?

Comment: F# isn't my best language, but unless I'm reading it wrong, `subscribeAfter` is basically ensuring that 1 comes before 3; Not that 2 comes before 3. As far as I can tell, you're just re-implementing `Concat`.

Comment: More fundamentally, there isn't really a notion of dependent observables. There's a couple of operators that join multiple observers in other ways than `Merge`: `Join`, `GroupJoin`, `Zip`, `And/Then/When`, etc..

Comment: You can get your desired effect with `Zip` for example, assuming all the observables are the same size.

Comment: I might be wrong but the intention of subscribeAfter was that it should behave similar to concat with the exception that it ignores the values of o1 and starts to yield values of o2 only after o1 has completed.

Comment: I think I've just understood the problem: the observables created by subscribeAfter don't depend on each other but they depend on the  observables created originally, before the subscribeAfter call.

Comment: Anyway now I'm a little confused regarding the purpose of this function. What I think I want is something like the observable happens-before contract on top of multiple observables